# C#'s Marshal.PtrToStringUni equivalent in Java

Tags: java, c#, pointers, marshalling, jna

While migrating code from `C#` to `Java` i stuck at the function `Marshal.PtrToStringUni`.

It converts a user input given as an `IntPtr` to a `String`. Is there a sollution to this probelm or at least a work around?

The pointers are provided by my beloved `JNA`.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: JNA provides a `Pointer.getWideString()` function, assuming your original pointer value represents a native `const wchar_t*`.

Comment: Thanks! It did the trick!